# let constant DATETIME() in SAS

Tags: sas

I have this code at the top of my code :

```
%let testDate = DATETIME();
```

and then various references through my code of the variable :

```
currentdate= &testDate.;
```

The thing is, I want testDate to be constant through my whole code so that everyone output has the same "currentdate". Per my understanding, when SAS compiles the code, it just replaces &testDate. by DATETIME() and therefore it's not constant everywhere.

My goal is to have DATETIME() computed, the output stored in testDate, and then replaced through the whole code as &testDate.

How could I do that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
%let testDate = %sysfunc(datetime());
```

What you are doing now is setting the macro to the function, not the return value of the function.  `%sysfunc()` resolves the function and you store the output.